# How do I pass a downloaded image from one activity to the next?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I would like to take a downloaded image the user clicked on from  on activity to the next. I believe this should be done in my lambda onItemClickListenerClass.

My code for my custom adapter class is here:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Movie movie = getItem(position);
      if  ( movie == null) return null;


        ImageView imageView;
        /**
         * if convertView is empty, set it equal to ImageView
         */
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(context);


            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(width, height));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        Uri coverUrl = movie.getMovieCover();
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(coverUrl)
                .into(imageView);

        //    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "URL " + url);


        return imageView;
    }
```

and this is code from my Object constructor class

```
public Uri getMovieCover(){
      final String BASE = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185";

    Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(BASE).buildUpon()
            .appendEncodedPath(poster_path)
            .build();

    return builtUri;
}
```

I have bundled all my string data into an extra and passed it through an intent, and I was thinking of doing the same thing in this context by converting the image into an extra and pass it through the intent, but I currently do not know how to implement that.

Can anyone help me with this problem? I am currently doing the Udacity Android Programmer final project so I still am fairly new to android programming.

Comment: Your code suggests you populated the ImageView from the Image URl and not explicitly downloaded the image to your sd card. You can do the same for 2nd activity. Pass the Image Url as String extra and again populate ImageView from the Url.

Comment: Sorry that I was not as specific as before, but the way the app is supposed to be programmed is through the use of parcelables which I know nothing about and I just need help implementing that functionality. Otherwise i would have used serialization and been done with it.

Comment: You didn't get my point.
Do you have the image url as string?

Comment: Yes I do have the image url as a string, and i also append an extra string due to each image in the main activity have a different url.

Comment: Ok check my answer than. Not the best explanation but may help you.

Comment: Ok thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the Url as String extra to 2nd Activity.

In 1st Activity/Custom Adapter :

```
String url = "http://image-url";
Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity().this, 2ndActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("image-url", url);
getActivity().startIntent(intent);
```

In 2nd Activity :

```
String url;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent i = getIntents();
    url = i.getExtra("image-url");

    Uri coverUrl = new Uri(url);

    if (url.Length() > 0) {
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(width, height));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(coverUrl)
                .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will re-download the image every time the activity starts

Comment: That's the drawback. Your best bet will be to download the image to your sd card than create a bitmap/bitmap drawable from file path.